# Does Azure Pack support auto scaling Web and Worker roles with WASABi?

Tags: azure, autoscaling, wasabi, azure-pack

[WASABi](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-autoscaling-application-block/) seems to support autoscaling of Web and Worker roles in Azure public cloud, however it's not clear if the same behavior can be applied to on site [Azure Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/default.aspx?nv1if0=1#fbid=L6kGIrAJxRZ) (private cloud) instances. Anyone know?

Comment: WASABi isn't really needed with the current SDK2.2 portal, since auto-scaling is a feature of the portal based on CPU or Queue size. Should be available soon in Azure Pack.

Comment: @viperguynaz I know you can do auto scale on Public Azure based on CPU or queue size, which is awesome and way more simple than using WASABi, however it is not currently a feature in Azure Pack - as far as I can tell. You mentioned "Should be available soon in Azure Pack" - are you sure about that? Do you know specifically when? I'm looking for a little more concrete information. Basically I have a auto scale problem to solve in the short term, and can't really wait for hypothetical features/release dates.

Answer (score 1):

**Auto Scaling is not supported on Azure Pack. Auto scaling is actually an azure wide feature that is not in Azure Pack yet.**

I don't have a timeline for your request for the feature yet. (Yes sadly even after an year)

Try Azure Service Fabric they have a lot of cool feature to scale your site up and down and they are connected to both on-premise and on azure. It is worth a look for your scenario.

**Happy to help, -CB**